Allowing use of nebula mesh network and commercial VPN simultaneously (Linux -- Ubuntu 22)?
I'm attempting to configure a server that can access the web over VPN (specifically Mullvad VPN) while simultaneously allowing access to other nodes on a nebula mesh network.
I've made some decent progress so far, having adjusted nft tables per the mullvad documentation to essentially split-tunnel all communications to the nebula lighthouse and to/from IPs within the nebula subnet.
At this point I am able to connect to Mullvad VPN as well as handshake and ping to/from my nebula lighthouse. However, I'm unable to ping to/from other nodes on the nebula subnet other than the lighthouse. I can verify that I am able to do so when mullvad vpn is disabled.
Here are the steps I took to get this far:
installed and configured nebula. Tested and working.
installed and configured mullvad vpn. Tested and working
"mullvad split-tunnel add 2673" #pid of nebula
applied nft rules to allow the server to contact the lighthouse, bypassing mullvad vpn
applied nft rules to exclude the nebula subnet from mullvad vpn routing

Here is my nft rule table:
#/opt/excludeTraffic.rules
# Documentation: https://mullvad.net/en/help/split-tunneling-with-linux-advanced#allow-incoming
#
# manually apply this file: sudo nft -f /opt/excludeTraffic.rules

# Define Nebula Lighthouses and Subnet
define NEBULA_LIGHTHOUSES = {
    27.111.51.239
}

define NEBULA_SUBNET = {
    10.42.0.0/16
}

table inet excludeTraffic {

  chain allowIncoming {
    type filter hook input priority -100; policy accept;
    tcp dport 22 ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65;
    ip daddr $NEBULA_SUBNET ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65;
  }

 chain allowOutgoing {
    type route hook output priority -100; policy accept;
    tcp sport 22 ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65;
    ip saddr $NEBULA_SUBNET ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65;
  }

  chain excludeOutgoing {
    type route hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    ip daddr $NEBULA_LIGHTHOUSES udp dport {4242} ct mark set 0x00000f41;
    ip daddr $NEBULA_SUBNET ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65;
  }

}

As mentioned, this configuration has allowed me to get nebula working partially while connected to mullvad vpn. I can communicate with the lighthouse both directly and through the nebula subnet, bypassing mullvad vpn. However, I still cannot communicate with other nodes on the nebula network, unless I disconnect from mullvad VPN.

AFAICT one (probable) mistake is that daddr in allowIncoming should be saddr whereas saddr in allowOutgoing should be daddr. (Both uses of daddr in excludeOutgoing are correct.)
